# Calculus Question including cross product.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to show the following relation holds where $u=f(x)$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg[u\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg]=\bigg[u\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}\bigg]
\end{equation}
Here is what I have so far,
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dx}\bigg[u\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg]=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(u\cdot\frac{du}{dx}\times \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
=u\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)+\frac{du}{dx}\cdot\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= u\cdot\bigg[\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\times\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)\bigg]+\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{du}{dx}\bigg(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)+\frac{du}{dx}\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\bigg)\times\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}
\end{equation}
If I now just cross off the entire right hand side of the last line from the square bracket then I can obtain the correct answer by;
\begin{equation}
u\cdot\bigg[\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\times\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\bigg)\bigg]=u\cdot\bigg(\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}\bigg)=\bigg[u\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d^3u}{dx^3}\bigg]
\end{equation}
So the question is, what happens to the rest of the right hand side?

Comment: Is there any significance to those brackets?  Especially on the right hand side.

Comment: This is false. Let $u = x^2$. Then $u' = 2x$ and $u'' = 2$. Hence $uu'u'' = 4x^3$ and $(uu'u'')' = 12x^2$. But $u''' = 0$ and hence $uu'u'''= 0$.

Comment: @Mike Forgive me I should have said that the brackets represent $[abc]=a\cdot b\times c=a\times b\cdot c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(u\cdot(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime}))=u^{\prime}\cdot(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime})+u\cdot(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime\prime}+u^{\prime\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime})$.

$\displaystyle=(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime})\cdot u^{\prime\prime}+u\cdot(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime\prime})+u\cdot(u^{\prime\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime})=u\cdot(u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime\prime})$

[since $u^{\prime}\times u^{\prime}=\vec{0}$ and $u^{\prime\prime}\times u^{\prime\prime}=\vec{0}$.]